# Firebase data save/retrieve stops working on Android after device sleeps for 3 minutes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` on Android, and it works great except for one major issue - the database updates stop functioning if I sleep the device for 3 minutes or longer.  Unfortunately I cannot reproduce with the debugger attached (or even with just USB cable connected and watching logcat output).

The steps to reproduce this bug are very simple, and occur 100% of the time using the stock android firebase quickstart app found here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Repro steps:

1. Run the app on a device (I am using an Android 5.1 tablet), verify that you can save a post and write comments, all works fine
2. Push power button on android device to put the device to sleep
3. Wait 3 minutes (the bug does not occur after 1 min or 2 mins, but is 100% reproducible after 3 mins)
4. Push sleep button again to wake device up and swipe up to view the still running app.
5. BUG: You cannot save posts or write comments, and have to log out/in or force quit and restart the app to get database functionality back.

I have tried the following with no luck:

- Creating/destroying the adapter in `onStop`/`onStart`
- Added a `CompletionListener` ==> `onComplete` is never called
- Checked that auth has a current user via `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` ==> it does
- Checked for exception in completion handler when getting user token with this call: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getToken()`  (from advice from a stock overflow post, can't find the link now but similar to this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=sl#!topic/firebase-talk/CjE9ra_nwrw) ==> task is successful, no exception

Any ideas what is needed to fix this?

Comment: Despite your very nicely formatted question, it is in danger of being close voted. You are missing an [mcve]. Please [edit] your question and provide one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (this was my first so post).  I've rewritten to be more concise and give detailed repro steps with the basic firebase android database sample app.